# IN operator for JQL in Jira Rest API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I would like to translate the following JQL query for an REST API call :
`project=XX AND component IN ("SomeTitle")`

first part of the url would be:

`/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=XX`

but how do I set the `component IN ("SomeTitle")` in the url ? What operator do I need to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what that URL would look like:

```
/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=XX%20and%20component%20in%20(%22SomeTitle%22)
```